# Comparing string to multiple strings in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, jupyter-notebook, operators

I'm trying to compare cell value of dataframe to some strings and concat that matched string in a variable but I'm getting error.
Could someone please check..!

```
route=''
for b in range(10):
   route+  = ('-'+ rail[0].index[b] +'-') if (rail[x].index[b] == ('WD' | 'POT' | 'NGI'))
```

Error I'm getting is:-

```
unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Edit: Adding some index values to work on

```
Index(['DW', 'NG', 'NGI', 'DW', 'WD', 'NGI', 'NF', 'FGH', 'NNI',
   'DWD','NGH', 'POT', 'NGI', 'DW', 'POT', 'NNGI', 'GH', 'NH', 'NGI',
   'WD'])
```

Comment: what is `rail`? Also you concatenate `string` with `+`, not `|`

Comment: It is some dataframe I'm working on and it's index are some values and I need to compare those index values to above stated few values ('WD' | 'POT' | 'NGI')..rail[0] might confuse you but my dataframe is lying in dictionary and I'm accessing 0th key dataframe to be more precise

Comment: can you post some sample for `rail[0]` then? Makes it easier to replicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to check whether your `rail[x].index[b]` is either of `('WD' | 'POT' | 'NGI')` on each iteration,

Try the below snippet if it is the case,

```
route=''
for b in range(10):
   route += ('-'+ rail[0].index[b] +'-') if (rail[x].index[b] in ('WD', 'POT', 'NGI'))
```

**Quick Check:**

```
print("WD" == ('WD' | 'POT' | 'NGI'))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

print("WD" in ('WD' , 'POT' , 'NGI'))

True
```

Comment: That worked just fine...funny I got downvoted on my question. lol